# Cookie not setting expire date correctly

Tags: php, magento, cookies

Im trying to set a cookie for 30 days but for some reason after its set it shows expires "session". Verified on Firefox and Chrome. I cant figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
  $name = 'db_mc';
  $value = $mc_cid . '-' . $mc_eid;
  $time = time()+3600*24*30;
  $path = '/';
  $domain = 'www.testmage.local';

  $cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');
  $cookie->set($name,$value,$time,$path,$domain);
```

Update:

I tested setcookie() and that works correctly. So I assume I have to use that. Does anyone know why the Magento version only sets for the session though?

Comment: What is the actual value of `$time` when you `echo` it?

Comment: Why not just use [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)?

Comment: I agree with Matt above. Do not use/build external functionality that does the same as PHP's internal functionality. it will save you time and will learn you to use PHP in a proper way.

Comment: Value of $time is 1348336723. I am using Magento's method because it is a Magento module extending native Magento code. Trying to keep it consistent.

Comment: Yes I am also facing the same issue like my cookie expiry date is setting as "session". But i am not getting the issue exactly why?

Answer (score 0):

Magento's cookies expiry datetime set always in seconds, you need to convert your date or time in seconds then you will set your cookies in magento accordingly.

Cookies set for one month in magento:

```
$expire = strtotime(date("m/d/Y, H:i:s A", time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30));
```

Output: 09/13/2015, 10:43:39 AM (calculate with current date).